# read/write internal storage android

Tags: java, android, storage, internal

I have a question regarding internal files in android.. I tried to write some data into a file and then read it back however, it seems like I can't write data to a file unless I cast it to an integer first.. is there anyway that I can save double or float values.. I added the code I'm trying to use below:

```
FormatCluster formatCluster = ((FormatCluster)objectCluster.returnFormatCluster(ofFormats,"Calibrated")); 
if (formatCluster != null) {
//Obtain data for text view
calibratedDataArray[0] = formatCluster.mData;
calibratedUnits = formatCluster.mUnits;
A.setText("data: " + formatCluster.mData);

String filename = "myfile";
//String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write((int)formatCluster.mData);//here I don't want to cast the value to integer
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

//testing.setText)

double ch;
StringBuffer fileContent = new StringBuffer("");
FileInputStream fis;
try {
fis = context.openFileInput( filename );
try {
while( (ch = fis.read()) != -1)
testing.setText(fileContent.append(ch));
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What type is `FormatCluster.mData`?

Answer (score 0):

Envelope your InputStream and OutputStream with a DataInputStream and a DataOutputStream. These classes have the method you need

Comment: could you refer me to a tutorial that shows how to do this, please?